# The app crashes when i pick image from gallery the second time. Have tried to call System.gc() to clear the memory, but didn't worked

Tags: android

2022-02-01 12:01:30.862 16616-16616/? E/ActivityThread: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity$1@efec398 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity has leaked IntentReceiver com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity$1@efec398 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:1607)
at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1378)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1624)
at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1611)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiverAsUser(ContextWrapper.java:720)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:98)
at com.android.internal.content.PackageMonitor.register(PackageMonitor.java:86)
at com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity.onCreate(ResolverActivity.java:523)
at com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity.onCreate(ChooserActivity.java:828)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8127)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8098)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1310)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3513)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3700)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8061)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
2022-02-01 12:01:30.871 714-721/? E/statsd: Predicate 5980654721335871649 dropping data for dimension key (10)0x2010101->10036[I] (10)0x30000->*launch*[S]
2022-02-01 12:01:30.897 18012-18012/com.athermobileapp E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 1250432)
2022-02-01 12:01:30.923 18012-18012/com.athermobileapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.athermobileapp, PID: 18012
java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1250432 bytes
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:161)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8061)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1250432 bytes
at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:593)
at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.activityStopped(IActivityTaskManager.java:4647)
at android.app.servertransaction.PendingTransactionActions$StopInfo.run(PendingTransactionActions.java:145)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8061) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't running out of memory, so calling gc won't help (its also not reliable, and not necessary as Java will run gc if it needs to).  Your problem is you're sending an intent that is too big.  See the part of the crash that says `android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: data parcel size 1250432 bytes`?  An intent's data can be a maximum of 1 MB.  You're at about 1.2 MB.  You need to decrease the amount of data in your intent.